# How do I access a specific value in the 'filter' function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

```
const initialState={
    current_memo:0,
    memolist:[
    ]
};

export default function todos(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case TOGGLE_TODO:
            const newId= state.memolist.filter(todos=>todos.id === action.id);
            console.log(newId);
            return {
                ...state,
                current_memo:newId
            }
```

filter function returns an array as shown below

```
{id: 1, title: "why?", text: "plz"}
```

How do I get the id value in this situation? 'newId.id' did not run properly

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a runnable snippet (using toolbar) so it demonstrates the problem when you do `newId.id`?

Answer (score 1):

newId will return array of objects which matches you condition. you can use as `let newId = [{id: 1, title: "why?", text: "plz"}];console.log(newId[0].id);`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need:

```
const value= state.memolist.find(todos=>todos.id === action.id);
newId = value && value.id
```